# How to check whether all values in grouped columns are the same?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

How do I check whether all the values in grouped columns are the same?

For example, I have the following df:

```
   id category yes
1   1       in   1
2   1       in   1
3   1       in   1
4   1       in   1
5   1       in   1
6   1      out   1
7   1      out   1
8   1      out   1
9   2       in   1
10  2       in   1
11  2      out   0
12  2      out   1
13  2      out   1
14  3       in   1
15  3       in   1
16  3       in   0
17  3      out   1
18  3      out   1
19  4       in   1
20  4       in   1
21  4       in   1
22  4      out   1
23  4      out   0
```

I want to do something like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id, category) %>%
  mutate(
    out = ifelse(# id, category, and yes have the same values in each row within the group)
  )
```

So the expected output will look like this:

```
   id category yes same
1   1       in   1    1
2   1       in   1    1
3   1       in   1    1
4   1       in   1    1
5   1       in   1    1
6   1      out   1    1
7   1      out   1    1
8   1      out   1    1
9   2       in   1    1
10  2       in   1    1
11  2      out   0    0
12  2      out   1    0
13  2      out   1    0
14  3       in   1    0
15  3       in   1    0
16  3       in   0    0
17  3      out   1    1
18  3      out   1    1
19  4       in   1    1
20  4       in   1    1
21  4       in   1    1
22  4      out   1    0
23  4      out   0    0
```

Rows 11-13 have the same "id" and "category" but the "yes" column has different values. Thus, the "same" column should be marked 0 (because they're not the same). Same with rows 14-16 and rows 22-23.

Here's the reproducible code for the df:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), category = c("in", 
"in", "in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "out", "in", "in", "out", 
"out", "out", "in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "in", "in", "in", 
"out", "out"), yes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `n_distinct` to check for frequency of unique elements in the group, convert to  logical (`== 1`) and then to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, category) %>% 
  mutate(same = +(n_distinct(yes) == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, same := +(uniqueN(yes) == 1), by = .(id, category)]
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it's taking a long time to run. (It's been 10 mins.) Is this normal?

Comment: @hy9fesh how big is your dataset? and how many groups

Comment: Almost a million rows. I've been able to run other dplyr commands without issue, though.

Comment: that should be fast.  You may also try with `data.table` i.e. `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, out := +(all(yes)), by = .(id, category)]`

Comment: @hy9fesh I guess it could be an issue when there are only 0 values per group.  Try the updated version of code

Answer (score 2):

One option if your data is a data.table.

I don't think this is a good solution in situations like this example where you only have one column to check. In that case you can use `uniqueN` like @akrun shows. If I'm remembering correctly, when you have many rows and many columns in your `cols` argument to the below function, this is faster because to use `uniqueN` in that case you'd have to first create a `data.table` from the cols you want to check, once per each group (`uniqueN` input must be vector or data.table). But, I don't have any benchmark so maybe I'm misremembering.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

check_single_value <- function(df, col_uq, by, show_groups = FALSE) {
  n_uq <- unique(df[, c(col_uq, by), with = FALSE])[, .N, by = by]
  if (show_groups)
    n_uq[N > 1]
  else 
    n_uq[, !any(N > 1)]
}

check_single_value(df, 'yes', by = c('id', 'category'))
#> [1] FALSE

check_single_value(df, 'yes', by = c('id', 'category'), show_groups = T)
#>       id category     N
#>    <int>   <char> <int>
#> 1:     2      out     2
#> 2:     3       in     2
#> 3:     4      out     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a simpler solution.

`df <- df %>% group_by(id, category) %>% mutate(n_unique = length(unique(yes)))`

That code will give you the number of unique values for yes within an id-category group. You can operate this to get the final outcome you want.